# Fast, efficient way to zoom/pan scatterplot with mouseover data

Tags: python, r, clustering, visualization, javascript

Given a csv of the form:

```
x, y, annotation
```

How can we efficiently (least code) generate an interactive (zoom/pan) scatterplot where the annotation appears when mousing-over or clicking on an individual point?

This is very helpful when evaluating clusterings.

Comment: All of them (at least, the ones you tagged: R, python, JS). So what?

Comment: Built-in in ELKI, no code required. Open the scatterplot, in the menu choose the label tooltip to enable the mouseovers.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it in Python, in a Jupyter notebook, with [`bokeh`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, BoxZoomTool, PanTool, WheelZoomTool

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your.csv")
source = ColumnDataSource(df_plot)
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("info", "@annotation")])
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools=[hover, BoxZoomTool(), PanTool(), WheelZoomTool()])
p.circle('x', 'y', size=7, source=source)

output_notebook()
show(p)
```

This gives you an interactive, exploratory chart right in the notebook.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to @Pete response (I don't have enough reputation to comment), if you're not using Jupyter just remove the `output_notebook()` line and add `output_file("csv_plot.html")` so it looks like this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, BoxZoomTool, PanTool, WheelZoomTool

import pandas as pddf = pd.read_csv("your.csv")

source = ColumnDataSource(df_plot)
output_file("csv_plot.html")
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("info", "@annotation")])
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools=[hover, BoxZoomTool(),     PanTool(), WheelZoomTool()])
p.circle('x', 'y', size=7, source=source)

show(p)
```

This will save the plot in your current working directory and then open the plot in your browser when it's done generating it.  Check out the [bokeh docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/quickstart.html) for more info